# Save session on startup web app with JDBCStore Tomcat 6.0

Tags: java, session, tomcat

I want to save tomcat sessions using this in $CATALINA_HOME/conf/context.xml

```
<Manager className="org.apache.catalina.session.PersistentManager"
    debug="99" saveOnRestart="false" processExpiresFrequency="3" minIdleSwap="-1" maxIdleSwap="-1" maxIdleBackup="1"  distributable="true">
    <Store className="org.apache.catalina.session.JDBCStore"
        connectionURL="jdbc:oracle:thin:myusr/mypass@//localhost:1521/mydb" 
        driverName="oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver" 
        debug="99"
        sessionAppCol="APP_NAME" 
        sessionDataCol="SESSION_DATA" 
        sessionIdCol="SESSION_ID"
        sessionLastAccessedCol="LAST_ACCESS" 
        sessionMaxInactiveCol="MAX_INACTIVE"
        sessionTable="TOMCAT_SESSIONS" 
        sessionValidCol="VALID_SESSION"
        cveUsuario="CVE_USUARIO" 
        ipCliente="IP_CLIENTE" />
</Manager>
```

but I need insert session immediately when user sends a request. With this configuration insert data session after 30 seconds.

Comment: Hi Tobert, welcome to StackOverflow, quick question, can you let us know what you've already tried to get this working?  It sounds like you're looking to persist your tomcat sessions within a data base of some description, am I right?  Sorry my Tomcat is rusty in the extreme.

Comment: Sorry I miss-typed your name there

Comment: i have persisted my tomcat sessions on my application's database. Sorry for my english

Comment: The PersistentManager is only defined to 'swap active (but idle) sessions out to a persistent storage mechanism, as well as to save all sessions across a normal restart of Tomcat.' Your expectations are misplaced. Possibly you should be using a SessionListener?

Comment: But see also [here](http://serverfault.com/q/321434/75336).

Comment: I've solved my problem. Using the PesristManager, i can persist sessions since users load the initial jsp and i can send additional information like username or remote ip address to generate tables on database something like an audit. Thaks for your comments